# Adding new methods to jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I'm creating a navigation bar that will be open depending on what page of the site you're on (the "selected" class generated by PHP)

I'm trying to make a method in jQuery and attach it to IDs of certain objects. I'd like to make it as modular as possible, I guess — and I'm trying to learn a bit more about OOP in javascript.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="workNav">Work</a></div>
<div  id="workNavContents">
  <a class="selected" href="foo.html">Video/Film</a>
  <a class="" href="foo.html">Photography</a>
</div>
<div id="clientsNav"><a href="#">Clients</a></div>
<div id="clientsNavContents">
  <a href="foo.html">Agencies/Clients</a>
  <a href="foo.html">Directors/Photographers</a>
</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
var showSelected = new function(){
    if ($(this).children('.selected')){
        $(this).show();
    }
}

$('#workNavContents').showSelected = showSelected; 
$('#workNavContents').showSelected();

$('#clientNavContents').showSelected = showSelected; 
$('#clientNavContents').showSelected();
```

Something tells me I'm sorely missing a crucial point of jQuery vs. javascript. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
M

Comment: I think jQuery plugins are what you are looking for http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: You haven't used the word "plugin", which is key here. You need to learn how to write jQuery plugins. Many examples/tutorials exist on the web. Don't try to guess; certain aspects are totally unguessable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...)` returns a new object every time you call it.

Instead, you need to add your method to jQuery's *prototype*:

```
$.fn.showSelected = function() { ... };
```

It will then be accessible through all jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely missing a little bit of understanding. jQuery makes it easy to allow customization from the user. All you need to do is access jQuery's prototype which they expose through `$.fn`. Once this is in place, your extension may be used.

Note that I chose fade so that it was obvious that it worked

```
var showSelected = function(){
  if ($(this).children('.selected')){
    $(this).hide().fadeIn(2000);
  }
}
$.fn.showSelected = showSelected;//you could also simply assign the function to this
$('#workNavContents').showSelected();
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mEgsX/

Also note that you do not need to use `new` on the function. That creates a function object and is a whole other conversation.

Comment: Long-time lurker, first-time poster. Would upvote this if I could. Thanks.